# Knockout select value to $data

Tags: knockout.js

I have two observable arrays, and they both hold objects of same model type:

array1 and array2

I have the following code

```
<!-- ko foreach: array2 -->

<select data-bind="options: $parent.array1(), optionsText: 'DisplayName', value: $data }">
</select>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Partial view model

```
array1 = ko.observablearray([])
//I then grab objects from a database and push them to this array1

array2 = ko.observalbearray([])
//now I loop through array1 and based on some conditions, add the matching objects to array2. So in essense, array2 is a subset of array1

//I also have some logic here where I have a computed observable that gets computed based on the array2, and hence it's important for me to detect changes to this array.
```

What I'm trying to do here is to assign the 'value' of select to the current item from array2 from the foreach loop. But when I change the value from the dropdown, I wish to change this in the corresponding array2, and notice for changes in array2. So let's say we have values 'a', 'b', 'c' in the dropdown (so this is array1), and say array2 is 'b', 'c', and now from the first of the two dropdowns (since array2 size is 2), I replace 'b' with 'a'. I want this change reflected in array2, and my computed observable value is recalculated.

With my code above, I can set the value but I don't notice the array changing. I'm not sure how to make this work. Any suggestions?

I should also add the the elements in array1 and array2 are not obervables)

Comment: Can you please post a minimal version of your view model, especially `array2` and `array1` data

Comment: I've added a partial view model, and also clarified my post below. I believe this now conveys my message better.